# Android Bluetooth Connection without Scan

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, uuid, network-scan

I'm currently working an appliction where i have.

- A server : my Computer.
- And a Client : my Android Device

I've already built a version of my program using http connection, but now, I want to connect to my server via Bluetooth. So I'm actually confused about something :

My phone will never connect to another device than my computer, so am I forced to make a Discovery on every device around and then loop on the `deviceAdapter` to find mine ?
My server(computer) is listenning for connection with this :

```
UUID uuid = new UUID("0000110100001000800000805F9B34FB", false);
                System.out.println(uuid.toString());

                String url = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid.toString() + ";name=MyServiceName";
                notifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open(url);
```

Isn't  `device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MON_UUID);` made for a  direct connection between two devices without discovery ?

Thank You in Advance.